# Open and close applications from Java

Tags: java, file, pid

I want to make a program to open and close applications you have installed on your computer.

I know that using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL "+"M:\\myfile.doc");
```

open the Word document myfile.doc

The problem is using this command can not close the Word application that opens when you execute the command.

How I can open and close applications from a java program?

Thank's!

Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try by storing the `Process`returned by `exec()` and calling `destroy()` on it but I don't think it will work since you are executing a windows command that launches a new process which is then not managed by the JVM (only the rundll32 thing is seen by JVM).

A solution that will work for sure but won't be cross-platform (I don't think you actually care since Word is not cross-platform too :) is to use another windows shell command to obtain what you want, like

```
taskkill /IM word.exe
```

You could execute it in the same way like you do to open word, with `defaultRuntime.exec(...)`. If you have many word processes opened and you want to kill a specific one you will have to parse the task list to obtain the correct PID and then try with `taskkill /PID XXXX`.

Comment: I just tried this out, it does work (after invoking `winword.exe` manually).

Comment: Thank's Jack an Mark, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the Java expert, however recently I had contact with the function mentioned by You. As I recall, Runtime.getRuntime().exec() return a Process class object.

You can try doing as follows:

```
Process word = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL "+"M:\\myfile.doc");
// some logic
word.destroy();
```

Maybe it will solve Your closing problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't actually kill Word.  It works for the general case I suppose.  It doesn't even work if you invoke Word directly (not through the shell).